# rgbdslam and octomap under ROS electric

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am quite confused by the octomap packages since it doesn't specify details on how to get it run on electric. I cannot update my ros to furte cuz my whole lab is using electric version.  Right now I'm trying to use octomap to save and view the map I get from rgbdslam package. But when I run

```
rosrun octomap_server octomap_saver filename.bt
```

it shows the following:

```
chong@ubuntu:~$ rosrun octovis octovis filename.bt
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named octovis below /home/chong/rospkg/octomap_mapping-experimental/octovis
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files, 
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/chong/rospkg/octomap_mapping-experimental/octovis
[rosrun]   /home/chong/rospkg/octomap_mapping-experimental/octovis/src/octovis
```

and by the way I've already done

```
chong@ubuntu:~$ cd rospkg
chong@ubuntu:~/rospkg$ svn co http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/branches/octomap_mapping-experimental/
Checked out revision 2780.
```

so does anyone know why this happens? and how can I solve it? and detailed instructions will be appreciated because I am new to ROS and even ubuntu... Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35548/rgbdslam-and-octomap-under-ros-electric/) by [Chong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2273/chong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2012-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You've checked out the source code but you have not compiled it.

$ rosmake --rosdep-install PACKAGE-NAME

---

Originally posted by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) with karma: 600 on 2012-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2